# Stream audio files uploaded dynamically

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis, streaming, media

I developing a Microsoft solution that uses WCF services, SQL Server database and IIS.

I have developed a WCF service to upload mp3 files to database, and now I want to make a stream with those files.

Searching on Internet I've found these possibilities:

- WCF with [MediaStreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (not recommended).
- [WMS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448620.aspx) (Windows Media Services).
- [IIS Media Services](http://www.iis.net/media).
- [Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming).
- Create my own service to send files.

It's a service where someone can upload a file, and this file will be available in an audio stream.

The client will be iOS (Objective-C), Android (Java) and Windows Phone (C#).

If I have to upload mp3 files, **what do you recommend me?**

Comment: What will be making the upload? Are we talking about a .NET client, iPhone, Android, etc.? I think the protocol you use depends on what's supported by the client device that will access the service.

Comment: The client will be iOS (Objective-C), Android (Java) and Windows Phone (C#).

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished creating a WCF host/client setup similar to what you're describing, including the need to support iOS and Android. What we did was using BasicHTTPBinding and SOAP messaging between the host and clients. We send huge binaries up and down between the host and client, in some cases >1GB and we do this by:

a) encoding the binary into the body of the XML message as base64 text (see code sample below). 
b) Also, when the binaries are >100MB, we use an interative approach to uploading/downloading, chunking the binaries into 100mb slices that are sent as packages and reassembled on the host or client. This helps avoid timeouts and other problems.
c) You didn't ask, but all this works well with SSL encryption.

BasicHTTPBinding is generic enough, and flexible enough, to support all kinds of client devices; it can handle anything you throw at it as long as it's within XML. Functionally, we create an XML message with a "text" section (into which we pack all our text-related information about the user, the download/upload type, etc.) and a "body" section into which we pack our binary. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
   <s:Body>
     <HostConnectResponse xmlns="http://SomeDomain"> 
     <HostConnectResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeDomain"> 
       <a:BodySection>binaries goes in here</a:BodySection>
       <a:TextSection>&lt;WebServiceParams&gt;&lt;DeviceType value=\"Laptop\" /&gt;&lt;StreamDirection value=\"Host\" /&gt;&lt;ServiceType value=\"FileTransferService\" /&gt;&lt;Direction value=\"Host\" /&gt;&lt;Method value=\"ping\" /&gt;&lt;/WebServiceParams&gt;</a:TextSection>

     </HostConnectResult> 
     </HostConnectResponse> 
   </s:Body> 
   </s:Envelope>
```

Good luck with your project.